# How can I change the permissions on a service with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have written a Windows service that I would like to keep Administrators from casually tampering with by removing their right to start/stop it.

Granted, an **Administrator can elevate to SYSTEM and do anything they want**, or even an admin can still suspend the service's threads or delete the service, but **this is meant to prevent casual tampering**.

I can do this using Process Explorer quite easily (see below) but I am not sure where to begin with Delphi. I've browsed the [SetAcl C++ source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/setacl/files/) (and I may use their OCX file), but I'd prefer to use a native Delphi solution if one already exists. If not, I'll work on cloning SetAcl functionality.

Does anyone have experience with this that they could share?

[image]

NOTE: I had advocated a screen capture tool written in Delphi in this post and I am removing it b/c it is unrelated. I'm leaving this note here so the comments will still make sense! Regards.

Comment: I find the Print Screen button works for my screen shot needs!

Comment: If an Administrator wants to stop the service, they'll stop the service. If they're trying they probably have a good reason. The solution is to restrict administrative access, not to restrict the rights of administrators.

Comment: @TrueWill -- agreed. And maybe I don't give enough credit to admins, but I am willing to bet if they can't "stop" the service they will give up. That's my point, to prevent cursory tampering...as I stated.

Comment: If I can't stop a service I will uninstall it.   Selective startup can prevent the service from starting which then can cause it to un-installed without any restrictions by the administrator.

Comment: Do we really need that screen-capture-utility-testimonials at the end?

Comment: Why don't you do it in Group Policy and make sure that the policy is updated every 5 minutes so that your wonderful service can live eternal

Comment: "That only downside" is really a major one. How could you possible recommend this software? The screenshot above doesn't look good at all (compare with WindowClippings, for instance, that is able to save windows with the alpha-channel shadows preserved). And what does it have to do with the question at hand?

Comment: I like Corel Draw's included screen capture software, which includes the mouse pointer, if you want it to.

Comment: (@Warren P: So does WindowClippings.)

Comment: @Mick: Unrelated to question? Check. Advertising? Check. Flagging as spam. Also, buy stuff! (see?)

Comment: @Mick: I wouldn't if it were related to the question *in any way at all*.

Comment: @Mick: Nothing a user does on a machine they are administering qualifies as "tampering". Your interfering with their ability to do so OTOH does.

Comment: @Mick: You might also want to mention the clothes you wore when you wrote your question, and the food you've eaten in the last 24 hours, because it clearly relates to the OP and his condition at the time of writing the question, which are areas worth highlighting.

Comment: @Piskvor --- Fair enough. I think it's related to the [Delphi] tag, but I can see how it is not related to my question. Regards.

Comment: @Mick: I am not offended, but the comment really does look misplaced! :)

Comment: @mghie - No, we aren't talking about "administrators" in my case, I'm talking about people with "admin" rights. Unfortunately certain decisions out of my control have led to people being given local administrative rights when they do not need them. They are knowledgeable enough to know how to stop a service, but their job is entirely unrelated to IT or managing their computer.

Comment: @Andreas --- fair enough, and I understand. I will remove it. Regards.

Comment: @Mick: I'm not offended by the suggestion - I would consider the tool helpful, even. But does it relate to "changing the permissions on a service with Delphi"? I fail to see any connection. I like turtles, and I may have written this in Opera 11 - is that of interest to people looking for information about service permissions in Delphi? I'd say "not at all". This site strives for high signal to noise ratio, not for irrelevant tangents.

Comment: @Piskvor - you make a good point and I have removed my comment based on the feedback. Regards.

Comment: @Mick: Regarding "people with admin rights," what you describe is not a technical issue, it's a social issue. Trying to solve it with tricks that other developers are comparing--quite fairly--to malware techniques is not the answer; the solution is user education.  If they want to kill the service, let them.  Then when something goes wrong because it's not running, tell them in the politest possible terms that "that's because you killed the service, you bloody idiot."

Comment: @Mason - I agree with you, but educating several hundred thousand users is out of scope.

Comment: @Mick: Several...hundred...thousand...Administrators. Whoa. That sounds painful enough on its own.

Comment: @Mick I've you've got that many users then use the right tool for the job, Group Policy. To do otherwise makes no sense. I was joking before when I commented, but if you really have that many users of your service then use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Piskvor --- you're telling me! The good news is as we migrate from XP to Win7, their admin rights are going away (for nearly all of them). So maybe we'll finally get to where only the real admins are the only ones with admin rights!

Comment: @David - You make a good point, but admins can circumvent group policy as easily as my service modifications: http://bit.ly/ezGnNM

Comment: @Mick My point is not that its harder to get around but that it is easy to administer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Administrators have rights on their computers, to do whatever they want.  Are you asking for a way to change how Administrator rights work on a computer?

Any software that prevents administrators from "tampering" with something under their control sounds suspiciously like either a rootkit, or some other malevolent software.  If the administrator wants your service off, you should provide your own quick tools to get it off, and you shouldn't (and probably can't) block them from doing it, either from Windows GUI or from SC.EXE or NET STOP on the command line.

That being said, if it's a Windows API you want a Delphi wrapper for, I would find the name of the API and search the JEDI API library for it. It looks like [JWSCL](http://jwscldoc.delphi-jedi.net./) would work.